# Meteor/Blaze/Mongo/ Spacebars Templating

Tags: javascript, mongodb, meteor, meteor-blaze, spacebars

Can one create an HTML table from documents within a Mongo collection, using `{{#each}}` braces AND pass a unique `{{> template}}` also from the Mongo document?

I've generated a table using `{{#each}}` and a Mongo collection.

I'd like to pass a new template into a collapsible/accordion `<div>`.

I want the user to be able to click on a table row to reveal more information.

I thought I could pass the template or HTML from the helper to the html with triple braces, but this has not worked.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. You should provide a code example of what you have tried and what has gone wrong.

Comment: See [dynamic templates](http://blazejs.org/api/templates.html#Template-dynamic)

Comment: Thank you for putting me on the right track Michael Floyd. And thanks Jeff for the edits.